# Error "https://next-auth.js.org/errors#adapter_error_getsessionanduser No metadata for "SessionEntity" was found"

Tags: next.js, next-auth

After I upgraded to NextJS 13.5 from 13.4 I started to get this error each time I'm trying to login. I'm using next-auth with TypeORM-Adapter connected to PostgreSQL.
The strange thing about it, is that I only get this error in production mode and not in development mode.

```
[next-auth][error][adapter_error_getSessionAndUser] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#adapter_error_getsessionanduser No metadata for "SessionEntity" was found. {
  message: 'No metadata for "SessionEntity" was found.',
  stack: 'EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "SessionEntity" was found.\n' +
    '    at t.DataSource.getMetadata (/home/guy/workspace/falkordb-cloud/.next/server/chunks/871.js:52:45111)\n' +
    '    at t.EntityManager.findOne (/home/guy/workspace/falkordb-cloud/.next/server/chunks/871.js:149:25750)\n' +
    '    at getSessionAndUser (/home/guy/workspace/falkordb-cloud/.next/server/chunks/871.js:150:415819)\n' +
    '    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)',
  name: 'EntityMetadataNotFoundError'
}
[next-auth][error][SESSION_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#session_error No metadata for "SessionEntity" was found. EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "SessionEntity" was found.
    at t.DataSource.getMetadata (/home/guy/workspace/falkordb-cloud/.next/server/chunks/871.js:52:45111)
    at t.EntityManager.findOne (/home/guy/workspace/falkordb-cloud/.next/server/chunks/871.js:149:25750)
    at getSessionAndUser (/home/guy/workspace/falkordb-cloud/.next/server/chunks/871.js:150:415819)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  name: 'GetSessionAndUserError',
  code: undefined
}
```

I tried to play with the code, but I couldn't find a solution it seems like something has changed in the way nextjs is building the code in 13.5

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue:

If the application redefines the entities used by the TypeORM-Adapter (like I do)
As explained in https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/typeorm#advanced-usage

After Next 13.5 it seems like Next is shortening the classnames in build time, e.g. from `AccountEntity` to `a`
The problem is that TypeORM is using the classname by default for the class lookup.
The solution is to set the classname in the decorator
e.g.

```
@Entity("AccountEntity", { name: "accounts" })
export class AccountEntity {
```

https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/8822